How to declare variables and use them to UPDATE each row based on the preceding row(s)
I'm looping through table1:
create table table1(id,"date",quantity,"value")as values
 (1,'2024-10-01',1,1)
,(2,'2024-10-02',1,1)
,(3,'2024-10-03',1,1)
,(4,'2024-10-04',1,1)
,(5,'2024-10-05',1,1)
,(6,'2024-10-06',1,1)
,(7,'2024-10-07',1,1);

and updating the column value with the value stored in the variable _previous_value (which I need to calculate the value of the next row in the loop).
Is there a better way to execute the update using those variables, without converting the command to a string?
Something like:
UPDATE table1 SET value = {_previous_value} WHERE table1.id = {_r.id};

I know I can use LAG() to get the value from the previous row, but in this specific case I need the function. It works as it is, I just want to know if there's a "correct" way to do this without concatenation and the EXECUTE command.
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION functiontest() 
RETURNS VOID LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $f$
DECLARE _r RECORD;
DECLARE _previous_value DOUBLE PRECISION := 0;
BEGIN

FOR _r IN
    SELECT table1.date, table1.id  
    FROM table1
    ORDER BY table1.date, table1.id
LOOP
    WITH c AS
    (   SELECT 
        table1.id,
        table1.quantity + _previous_value AS total
        FROM table1 
        WHERE table1.id = _r.id 
        ORDER BY table1.date, table1.id
        LIMIT 1
    )
    SELECT
    COALESCE(c.total, 0)
    INTO
    _previous_value
    FROM c;

    EXECUTE 
    'UPDATE table1 SET value = ' || _previous_value || 
    ' WHERE table1.id = ' || _r.id || ';';
END LOOP;
END $f$;

DB<>Fiddle

You can sum(quantity)over(order by date,id). If you do that in a CTE or a subquery, it could be used as a source for the update, in which case you can make this a simple prepared statement or a plain SQL routine. Looping in PL/pgSQL, while intuitive, typically performs far worse than an equivalent in pure, declarative SQL.

Answering "Is there a better way to execute the update using those variables, without converting the command to a string?": execute..using. Or, let the update take the data from the select directly: with c as(..) update table1 set value=coalesce(c.total,0) from c where c.id=table1.id;


Is there a better way to execute the update using those variables, without converting the command to a string? (...) a "correct" way to do this without concatenation and the EXECUTE command.

To avoid concatenation, you can execute..using: demo1 at db<>fiddle
EXECUTE $dsql$ UPDATE table1 
               SET value = $1 
               WHERE table1.id = $2 ;
        $dsql$ USING _previous_value, _r.id;

To avoid execute entirely, you can let the update read from the select directly:
demo2 at db<>fiddle
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION functiontest() 
RETURNS VOID LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $f$
DECLARE _r RECORD;
        _previous_value DOUBLE PRECISION := 0;
BEGIN
FOR _r IN SELECT table1.date, table1.id  
          FROM table1
          ORDER BY table1.date, table1.id
LOOP WITH c AS(
      SELECT table1.id
           , table1.quantity + _previous_value AS total
      FROM table1 
      WHERE table1.id = _r.id 
      ORDER BY table1.date
             , table1.id
      LIMIT 1
    ),updated as(
      UPDATE table1 
      SET value = COALESCE(c.total, 0)
      FROM c
      WHERE table1.id = c.id
      RETURNING value)--value used in that update gets returned
    SELECT value 
    FROM updated 
    INTO _previous_value;--and saved for the next iteration
END LOOP;
END $f$;

Keep in mind you're by default in read committed transaction isolation mode, so unless you add some sort of locking, you might see anomalies if a concurrent client decides to insert into/update/delete from that table while you're in the middle of looping over it.

You could also run this whole update operation in one go, in a single plain SQL query:
demo3 at db<>fiddle
with new_state as (
   select id
        , sum(quantity)over(order by date,id) as new_value
   from table1)
update table1
set value=new_value
from new_state
where table1.id=new_state.id;

Looping in PL/pgSQL, while intuitive, typically performs worse than an equivalent in plain SQL so this should also speed things up. In a test on 200k random rows, doing the same thing takes:

23.4s using your initial function
23.1s with the addition of execute..using, about the same
10.9s if you allow the update to read the previous value directly, removing execute
3.7s for the plain SQL update above

